# GSS authentication for openssh client (Scientific Linux)

Tags: openssh

The task in hand is to look for an authentication mechanism from Linuix client (Scietific **Linux** 6.1) to a HyperV Server. I'm using openwsman to establish the connection; it seems openwsman does not support kerbose/gssapi as openssl/openssh internally used does not support the protocol.

Googling about GSS and openssh support, I was able to find a git project maintained by Simon Wilkinson (https://github.com/SimonWilkinson/gss-openssh) and also a webpage maintaining the patches against openssh releases (http://www.sxw.org.uk/computing/patches/openssh.html). But both this project are based on OpenBSD platform.

Does anyone have ported this changes for linux? Or anyother mechanism to get GSS authentication working on Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://grid.ncsa.illinois.edu/ssh contains the port for GSS protocol and seems to maintain pacthes against openssh very well.